# Rails: Public Folder File (CSV) is not updating data after the new updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are running a **Rails 5.2** app in **Heroku**, and I am keeping a sample CSV under the public folder.
Recently we have updated the CSV by adding a new column, but after we release that, when someone tries to download the sample CSV through the app,

not getting the newly added column for everyone, but some work in chrome and some in other browsers.

Below code is to download the sample items.

```
<a href="/sample_items.csv" download="sample_items.csv">Download our sample CSV file.</a>
```

Also, we have this in production.rb

```
config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
  }

config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

Is this something with the browser/CDN/assets or related to the cache?